# Receiving Subscript out of Range Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Macro and the

```
Sheets("Query[Difference in date]").Formula = "=[Posting Date]-[Expected Receipt Date]"
```

and

```
Sheets("Query[Grade]").Formula = _
"=IF([Difference in date]<2,""A"",IF([Difference in date]=2,""B"",IF([Difference in date]=3,""C"",IF([Difference in date]=4,""D"",""F""))))"
```

are giving me an

> Error 9 - Subscript out of Range error.

Any suggestions?

```
Sheets("Query").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Difference in date"
Range("K3").Select
Sheets("Query[Difference in date]").Formula = "=[Posting Date]-[Expected Receipt Date]"
Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Grade"
Range("L3").Select
Sheets("Query[Grade]").Formula = "=IF([Difference in date]<2,""A"",IF([Difference in date]=2,""B"",IF([Difference in date]=3,""C"",IF([Difference in date]=4,""D"",""F""))))"
Sheets("Pivot Table").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
```

This Macro refreshes a Query Table, then adds two columns to the right with formulas, then it refreshes the Pivot Table that References the Query table.

Comment: Are there any errors (e.g. #N/A, #VALUE!, etc) in that table?

Comment: `.Formula` is not valid property for `Sheet` object, as far as I remember. You should use `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(AddressString).Formula`